# Best way to persist images in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-image-crop-picker. 
Can someone tell what is the best way to persist the images (+over upgrades)? Do I need to move them from the original path/uri I get them?
Using some react native file system package (like react-native-fetch-blob)?

Couldn't find any example for that.

Thanks,
EyalS